# how to center text inside this <div> element?

Tags: html, css, centering

Here is an **h3** inside a **div** (using inline styles which I know is bad).

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 500px; height: 36pt; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="font-family: Helvetica;">Hello World!</h3></div>
```

How can I center the **h3** tag inside the **div**?

Comment: Center vertically or horizontally?

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tasks.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easy centering vertically you can set the `H3` `line-height` the same as the height of the container (if known).

In this case, we do (as you have set it to 36pt), i.e : `line-height: 36pt`

**Line-height Example:**

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 500px; height: 36pt; text-align: center;">
  <h3 style="font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 36pt">Hello World!</h3>
</div>
```

If the height of the container is dynamic and not known, you will need to use another form of vertically centering, such as using **display: table** or **display:flex**

**This resource about centering content in CSS is very useful for finding the best solution: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/**

Answer (score 2):

You can add line-height: 36pt to h3 tag.

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 500px; height: 36pt; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 36pt">Hello World!</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `line-height` which depends on the height of your `<div>`

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 500px; height: 36pt; text-align: center;">
   <h3 style="font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 36pt">Hello World!</h3>
</div>
```

take a look at this [example fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kcNeko/d2y7bLdd/)